# How to solve "app is still in review but requiring additional time"?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, review

I submit a app to App Store, but it is always rejected.How to solve this question?

[image: rejected pic1]

[image: rejected pic2]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you need to wait until they have finished reviewing your app

Comment: what type of rejection???

Comment: 0. 4.0 BEFORE YOU SUBMIT: INFO NEEDED

Comment: your app is required login credential because this problem is come when you does not give the proper information to apple review team. you have to provide the correct login credential.

Comment: My app does not need to log in, so I do not have to provide login credentials.

Comment: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0):

I submitted my app on Sep. 7th, but it always was rejected with the reason that "your app is still in review but requiring additional time". Yesterday,I appealed to the APP Review Committee，and then I find my app's status is "for sale" today.